# How to handle the heap memory garbage?

Tags: c++, garbage

So I have this code where a PiggyBank object is created. There are three if statements depending on a choice. Since the keyword **new** allocates the object in the heap how should I properly manage the memory garbage,so when a different type of constructor is created, the old piggy bank will disappear, in the following code:

```
while(fChoice!=""){
        showFunctions();
        PiggyBank *pb;

        cin>>fChoice;
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');

        if(fChoice=="a") {
            pb = new PiggyBank();
        }
        else if (fChoice=="b"){
            cout<<"ENTER NAME:"<<endl;
            string name = "";
            cin>>name;
            pb = new PiggyBank(name);
        }
        else if (fChoice=="c") {
            cout<<"ENTER NAME:"<<endl;
            string name = "";
            cin>>name;
            cout<<"ENTER STARTING BALANCE:"<<endl;
            int startBalance = 0;
            cin>>startBalance;
            pb = new PiggyBank(name,startBalance);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you use a smart pointer?

Comment: I assume you want to use `pb` after the `while` loop. If so, then the declaration of `pb` belongs before `while`. As it is right now, `pb` goes out-of-scope at the end of the `while` iteration and won't be usable for anything.

Comment: Not really. It is for a school project and the teacher does not like the new features of the language. It should be the old way.

Comment: @uneven_mark but does not the new keyword makes memory for it in the heap as well? So if it does it should stay even after the while loop is over or I am mistaken?

Comment: @Fiphe The memory for the `PiggyBank` does, but the pointer doesn't, since it is declared inside the loop iteration, not outside of it.

Comment: I see. How do I get rid of the memory then?

Comment: @Fiphe See my answer below. You don't need `new` at all. If the first code block in my answer gives you an error message, then ask a question about that. Don't try to work around it by using `new`.

Comment: @uneven_mark Hm, yes I did as shown in your answer but now when trying to access the balance and the name of the owner I get 0 and "" values,respectively. While when with the new keyword it used to assign them properly.

Comment: @Fiphe Then you have a problem somewhere else in your code. My answer initializes the objects in exactly the same manner as your code does. There should be no difference in values, so you probably have either undefined behavior somewhere else in your program or you have not correctly implemented the `PiggyBank` class. I suggest you make a [repro] of this new problem and ask a new question with it.

Comment: @Fiphe As pointed out by user4581301 under my answer, it is quite likely that you are violating the [rule of 0/3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) in your class if you get wrong values. You need to always follow that rule.

Comment: Adding the definition of `PiggyBank` could help us clear up some of the outstanding problems, but might clutter this question. I recommend reading the material on the Rule of Three and friends and applying it if you haven't already. If you come away with new question, or you already applied it, I recommend asking a new question.

Comment: I moved the pb outside the while but still within the function and it worked.

Comment: Why did that work? Could somebody explain?

Comment: Not without a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use dynamic memory allocation in the first place. There is no apparent reason for it here:

```
while(fChoice!=""){
        showFunctions();
        PiggyBank pb;

        cin>>fChoice;
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');

        if(fChoice=="a") {
            pb = PiggyBank();
        }
        else if (fChoice=="b"){
            cout<<"ENTER NAME:"<<endl;
            string name = "";
            cin>>name;
            pb = PiggyBank(name);
        }
        else if (fChoice=="c") {
            cout<<"ENTER NAME:"<<endl;
            string name = "";
            cin>>name;
            cout<<"ENTER STARTING BALANCE:"<<endl;
            int startBalance = 0;
            cin>>startBalance;
            pb = PiggyBank(name,startBalance);
        }
}
```

(of course there is some dependence on the definition of `PiggyBank` here)

---

If you *need* to allocate dynamically (and you better have a very good reason for it), use `std::unique_ptr` which is a smart pointer that handles the deletion automatically for you when it goes out-of-scope or is assigned a new pointer.

```
while(fChoice!=""){
        showFunctions();
        std::unique_ptr<PiggyBank> pb;

        cin>>fChoice;
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');

        if(fChoice=="a") {
            pb = new PiggyBank();
        }
        else if (fChoice=="b"){
            cout<<"ENTER NAME:"<<endl;
            string name = "";
            cin>>name;
            pb = new PiggyBank(name);
        }
        else if (fChoice=="c") {
            cout<<"ENTER NAME:"<<endl;
            string name = "";
            cin>>name;
            cout<<"ENTER STARTING BALANCE:"<<endl;
            int startBalance = 0;
            cin>>startBalance;
            pb = new PiggyBank(name,startBalance);
        }
}
```

(requires `#include<memory>`)

Comment: This is the "Right" way to do this, but make absolutely certain that `PiggyBank` correctly observes [the Rule of Three, Five, or Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) before trying it.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, but the rule of 0/3/5 needs to be satisfied in any case (otherwise it is just a bug waiting to manifest) and not using `new` all of the time will make that much easier. Using `new` to avoid manifesting problems with the rule of 0/3/5 is the wrong approach.

Comment: Yep, but the order is important. Fix code with non-compliant class and the fix doesn't look like it worked. If the fix doesn't work, asker wanders off and probably does something stupid that looks like it worked instead